# Coda for visualizing Stan trajectories

Tags: r, stan

I'm using [Stan](http://mc-stan.org/) (specifically, rstan) with a Bayesian univariate linear regression $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \varepsilon$.  And I'm trying to use the Coda package to visualize the resulting trajectories and distributions for the $\beta$s.  However, this produces the error `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`.  `traceplot` and `densplot` seem to work fine.  The problem seems to be with `plot.mcmc`, which is supposed to produce a nice panel output.  You can see an example of the expected output [here](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~plam/teaching/methods/convergence/convergence_print.pdf), on slide "Traceplots and Density Plots".

Here's a minimum (non-)working example using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
library(rstan)
library(coda)

stanmodel <- "
data {                     // Data block: Exogenously given information
    int<lower=1> N;        // Sample size
    vector<lower=1>[N] y;  // Response or output. 
                           // [N] means this is a vector of length N
    vector<lower=0, upper=1>[N] x;  // The single regressor; either 0 or 1
}

parameters {               // Parameter block: Unobserved variables to be estimated
    vector[2] beta;        // Regression coefficients
    real<lower=0> sigma;   // Standard deviation of the error term
}

model {                    // Model block: Connects data to parameters
    vector[N] yhat;        // Regression estimate for y
    yhat <- beta[1] + x*beta[2];

    // Priors
    beta ~ normal(0, 10);
    // To plot in R:  plot(function (x) {dnorm(x, 0, 10)}, -30, 30)

    sigma ~ cauchy(0, 5);  // With sigma bounded at 0, this is half-cauchy
                           // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution
    // To plot in R:  plot(function (x) {dcauchy(x, 0, 5)}, 0, 10)

    // Likelihood
    y ~ normal(yhat, sigma); // yhat is the estimator, plus the N(0, sigma^2) error
                             // Note that Stan uses standard deviation
}
"

# Designate data
nobs <- nrow(mtcars)
y <- mtcars$mpg
 x <- mtcars$am  # Simple regression version doesn't include constant
data <- list(
    N = nobs,                  # Sample size or number of observations
    y = y,                     # The response or output
    x = x            # The single variable regressor, transmission type
)

# Set a seed for the random number generator
set.seed(123456)

# Run the model
bayes = stan(
    model_code = stanmodel, 
    data = data, # Use the model and data we just defined
    iter = 12000,          # We're going to take 12,000 draws from the posterior, 
    warmup = 2000,         # But throw away the first 2,000
    thin = 10,             # And only keep every tenth draw.
    chains = 3             # But we'll do these 12,000 draws 4 times. 
)

# Use the coda library to visualize parameter trajectories and distributions 
param_samples <- 
    as.data.frame(bayes)[,c('beta[1]', 'beta[2]')]
plot(as.mcmc(param_samples))
```

Comment: If you are using RStudio, it may simply be the case that your plot window is too small. Try maximizing its size and dragging the divider to the left to make the plot window bigger. If that is not applicable / sufficient, try writing the plot to the disk by first calling something like `pdf('my_plot.pdf')`, then `plot(...)`, then `dev.off()`. Then see if there is anything interesting or valuable in the my_plot.pdf file that would suggest more about the nature of the problem.

Comment: Ah, that seems to have been the problem!  RStudio is so good at scaling plot windows, I hadn't realized that it would generate this kind of error if things were too small.